# Updating a field in a Netsuite record with data from a text area

Tags: backbone.js, netsuite, suitecommerce

I've been working with SCA for a little while now but I need some help when it comes to moving data from the front-end into the Netsuite backend.

I'm working for a client that requires a textarea at checkout that allows the user to add some information into the quote record in Netsuite.

So here is the my expected outcome:

User adds a comment into text field in the Request Quote confirmation page.

On submit the 'memo' field in the Quote model is updated to what text the user has submitted.

(this is where I'm getting stuck)

The 'memo' field in the model will then update the 'memo' field on the Quote Record and displayed in Netsuite Quote record.

OR

The 'memo' field will create a new custom field on the Quote record.

I'm essentially trying to figure out the data flow, from Netsuite records to front-end and vice versa. I'd like to be able to create custom fields and map them to the front-end UI as well.

Any help is very much appreciated!

[Here is the HTML for the text area including selectors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCez6.png)

[Here is the submit function that adds the val() to the memo field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcH8p.png)

P.S I'm using Vinson, so unfortunately can't use an extension as I would expect in the latest SCA.

Comment: What do you mean by NetSuite backend? Are you talking about some record?

Comment: What record are you saving this in? Do you need help getting it into a backbone model or do you have it through to the back end but need to persist it to a sales order or customer record?

Comment: Hey @Viks i've updated my question, hopefully this gives some more clarity. The record I need to add data, or update data is the Quote record.

Comment: @bknights it needs to be added the Quote record in Netsuite, so far I've added the val() of the text area to the model, but from there not sure what the next step is.

Comment: Update: I've added this to the backbone model, problem is it's not saving it. It's added on submit but after when the quote confirmation page loads the title field is still null and the record hasn't been updated. @bknights any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add custom fields in SCA you need to modify both the client and server models.

Your client models are all in some Javascript folders and your server models are all in SuiteScript folders. The recommended way to do this is by extending the base classes with overrides or extensions.

You also need to make sure your custom field shows up in the Netsuite UI -- you need to make sure the field is checked for "Sale" type transactions.